# Meta-analysis of fruits in blocking Cytochrome family

Tags: biochemistry, pharmacology

My professor says that some drugs cannot be used with grapefruit. 
I am trying to search a list of cytochromes and their effect to block members in the cytochrome family. Some in Cyt P450.

**What is the main meta-analysis of fruits in blocking cytochrome family?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I haven't found a list which is restricted to fruits, I found this page: [P450 Drug interaction table](http://medicine.iupui.edu/clinpharm/ddis/main-table/). They list quite a number of substances which inhibit different isoforms of the P450 protein and also give the original references.

This [list](http://www.pharmacologyweekly.com/content/pages/medications-herbs-cytochrome-p450-cyp-enzyme-inhibitors) gives a large number of herbals which inhibit different P450 isoenzymes. The disadvantage is that they do not give further references so if you want to have a closer look you will probably have to spend some time with Pubmed.

Comment: Thank you! The table includes the grapefruit juice as moderate inhibitor that was emphasized by my lecturer. I did not see any other significant food there.

Comment: The second list contains a number of latin names of different plants. If you translate them into the normally used ones (Wikipedia is helpful here) you can see if there are other fruits among them.

Comment: I asked my old Latin teacher how to learn the latin names of different fruit. I think there is some logic behind the fruit names.

Comment: Add the complete latin name into the search field of the Wikipedia to get the normally used name. Works pretty well.

Comment: Any possibility of doing it for those all at once? Doing list search?